# how to get file creation date in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get file creation date into a variable in powershell, however unable to do so. The "$_.CreationTime" just prints the string literal ".CreationTime". How to get actual creation time of file?

```
    $builds = Get-ChildItem "$path_to_directory" *.zip | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt $lastBuildDeployedTimestamp}
    foreach($build in $builds)
    {
                            "$path_to_directory"
                            "$_.CreationTime"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "$($_.CreationTime)" .

In your particular example it should be "$($build.CreationTime)"

Answer (score 0):

A one liner approach would be
`Get-ChildItem $path_to_directory *.zip | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt $lastBuildDeployedTimestamp} | Select-Object -Property FullName, CreationTime`

However, if you'd like to keep your loop then you'll need to use `$build`.

```
$builds = Get-ChildItem $path_to_directory *.zip | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt $lastBuildDeployedTimestamp} 
foreach($build in $builds)
{
    $path_to_directory
    $build.CreationTime
}
```

For more info see `Get-Help about_Foreach -Full`